# Can I use my Ubuntu notebook's display as second external monitor for my Windows desktop?

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, laptop, windows-10, external-monitor

I have two different devices: A notebook running Ubuntu and a desktop computer running Windows 10.

I want to connect my notebooks display to my desktop computer as additional external monitor.
Is this possible and how can it be achieved?

Comment: As you want to run Windows and let it use the notebook display as external monitor, this question should rather be asked on [su] where all operating systems are welcome. Here we can only cover Ubuntu questions.

Comment: Thank you, can I transfer this question to that plattform so othery may benefit from it as well?

Answer (score 0):

Notebook display does not have input jack, most likely. So answer is NO.

Comment: Not sure if your answer is useful. There might be ways how you could connect the two computers (maybe via USB or network) and let the notebook display show the desktop's second screen's content.